# Ошибка 404, 403 nginx

Tags: nginx, static, nginx-faq

В общем, вот основной конфиг:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    include /Users/kot_mapku3/Downloads/stepic/Web-технологии/github/etc/nginx.conf;

    sendfile on;
    include servers/*;
}
```

Собственно, вот конфиг, который я подключаю с помощью `include`

```
server {
listen 8080;
server_name localhost;
root /Users/kot_mapku3/Downloads/stepic/Web-технологии/github;
autoindex on;

  location / {
    root /Users/kot_mapku3/Downloads/stepic/Web-технологии/github;
  }

  location /uploads/ {
    root /Users/kot_mapku3/Downloads/stepic/Web-технологии/github/uploads;
  }

  location ~ \..+$ {
    root /Users/kot_mapku3/Downloads/stepic/Web-технологии/github/public;
  }
}
```

Но если зайти на localhost:8080, то он выдаёт ошибку `403`, а на отдачу любого файла говорит `404`.

Comment: В root'ах у uploads и public сотрите эти самые uploads и public. На localhost:8080 и должна быть ошибка 403, потом что вы не настроили никакую главную страницу

Comment: @andreymal стёр, там действительно ошибка была. Но я ещё долго не мог перезапустить, конфиг менял, может оно как-то ещё поменялось случайно

Comment: Как вариант, у nginx-а нет прав на чтение вашей домашней директории

Comment: @AlexeyTen а вот в том то и дело, что user у процесса отображается как ???, а права на папку 755